# Setting delay between automatic interactions with my GUI (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently coding the Towers of Hanoi Game. I want to have an automatic version which uses my algorithm and has a delay between each step. I already tried to use Timer from Java, but it still doesnt work.

This is the timer of my code.

```
public void startDelay() {
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                delayTimer.stop();
            }
        };
        delayTimer = new Timer(delay, action);
        delayTimer.setInitialDelay(500);
}
```

And this is an example where i want to use it.

```
public void algorithm() {
        while(tower3.count() != 3) {
            move1();
            move2();
            move3();

        }
    }

    public void move1() {

        getHeadLength();

        if (tower3.count() == 3) {
            return;
        }

        if (headT1 > headT3 && headT3 != 0) {
            getBlock(tower3);
            startDelay();
            setBlock(tower1);
            startDelay();
            commitChange();
            startDelay();
            return;
        }
}
```

Does somebody have an idea how I could implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Timer` to perform the required action (move) or actions, as demonstrated in the following [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
The action in the following demonstration is simply writing text in a `JTextField`:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SwingMain {

    private int phase = 1;
    private Timer moveTimer;

    SwingMain() {
        creategui();
    }

    void creategui(){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new APanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class APanel extends JPanel{

        private final JTextField tf;
        private final JButton start;

        APanel() {
            start = new JButton("Start");
            start.addActionListener(e-> startTimer());
            add(start);
            tf = new JTextField("Click Start",6);
            add(tf);
        }

        void startTimer() {

            start.setEnabled(false);
            ActionListener action = e -> autoPlay();

            moveTimer = new Timer(2000, action);
            moveTimer.setInitialDelay(500);
            moveTimer.start();
        }

        private void autoPlay() {

            switch (phase){
                case 1:
                    phase++;
                    move1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    phase++;
                    move2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    phase++;
                    move3();
                    break;
                default:
                    phase = 1;
                    moveTimer.stop();
                    tf.setText("Click Start");
                    start.setEnabled(true);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void move1() {
            tf.setText("Move 1");
        }

        private void move2() {
            tf.setText("Move 2");
        }

        private void move3() {
            tf.setText("Move 3");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingMain();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Timer is used to schedule an event in the future. It does NOT stop current processing.

So for example your ActionListener used for the first `setDelay() code might be changed to do two things:

1. setBlockTower(...)
2. start another Timer.

The second Timer would then do:

1. commitChange()

So the basic structure of your code needs to change to invoke a series of Timer that each does a different function.

Or the other approach is to have a single Timer that keeps track of the current `state` of the Timer. So every time the Timer fires you check the state and then execute the appropriate method for the current `state` and then you update the `state`.